# How to create a simple Proxy to access web servers in C

Tags: c, sockets, proxy, webproxy

I’m trying to create an small Web Proxy in C. First, I’m trying to get a webpage, sending a GET frame to the server.
I don’t know what I have missed, but I am not receiving any response. I would really appreciate if you can help me to find what is missing in this code.

```
int main (int argc, char** argv) {
   int cache_size,     //size of the cache in KiB
       port,
       port_google = 80,
       dir,
       mySocket,
       socket_google;

   char google[] = "www.google.es", ip[16];
   struct sockaddr_in socketAddr;
   char buffer[10000000];

   if (GetParameters(argc,argv,&cache_size,&port) != 0)
       return -1;

   GetIP (google, ip);
   printf("ip2 = %s\n",ip);

   dir = inet_addr (ip);
   printf("ip3 = %i\n",dir);

   /* Creation of a socket with Google */
   socket_google = conectClient (port_google, dir, &socketAddr);
   if (socket_google < 0) return -1;
   else printf("Socket created\n");

   sprintf(buffer,"GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n");
   if (write(socket_google, (void*)buffer, MESSAGE_LENGTH+1) < 0 )
       return 1;
   else printf("GET frame sent\n");

   strcpy(buffer,"\n");
   read(socket_google, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

   // strcpy(message,buffer);
   printf("%s\n", buffer);

   return 0;
}
```

And this is the code I use to create the socket. I think this part is OK, but I copy it just in case.

```
int conectClient (int puerto, int direccion, struct sockaddr_in *socketAddr) {
   int mySocket;
   char error[1000];

   if ( (mySocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
       printf("Error when creating the socket\n");
       return -2;
   }

   socketAddr->sin_family = AF_INET;
   socketAddr->sin_addr.s_addr = direccion;
   socketAddr->sin_port = htons(puerto);

   if (connect (mySocket, (struct sockaddr *)socketAddr,sizeof (*socketAddr)) == -1) {
       snprintf(error, sizeof(error), "Error in %s:%d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
       perror(error);
       printf("%s\n",error);
       printf ("-- Error when stablishing a connection\n");
       return -1;
   }
   return mySocket;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't post the `GetIP` routine, I am not certain that your hostname lookup is correct, as from the looks of it, I am not sure that you are using `inet_addr` function correctly.

Nikolai has pointed out some very good points (and I fully agree). In fact you `GET` request is actually broken, and while I was testing it on my own local Apache web server on my system, it didn't work.

```
sprintf(buffer,"GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n");
if (write(socket_google, (void*)buffer, LONGITUD_MSJ+1) < 0 )
    return 1;
else printf("GET frame sent\n");
...

strcpy(buffer,"\n");
read(socket_google, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

should be replaced with

```
  snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 
      "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\nUser-Agent: TEST 0.1\r\n\r\n", 
      google);

  if (write(socket_google, buffer, strlen(buffer)+1) < 0 ) {
      close(socket_google);
      return 1;
  } else 
      printf("GET frame sent\n");
  ...

  buffer[0] = '\0';
  /* Read message from socket */
  bytes_recv = read(socket_google, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
  if (bytes_recv < 0) {
       fprintf(stderr, "socket read error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
       close(socket_google);
       exit(10);
  }

  buffer[bytes_recv] = '\0';    /* NUL character */

  /* strcpy(message,buffer); */
  printf("%s\n", buffer);

  ...
```

You should also `close` the socket before exiting the program. Enable standard C89/90 or C99 mode of your compiler (e.g. `-std=c99` for gcc) and enable warnings (e.g. `-Wall` for gcc), and read them. And `#include` the necessary header files (assuming Linux in my case) for function prototypes:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <errno.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <netinet/in.h>
 #include <arpa/inet.h>
 #include <netdb.h>      /* for gethostbyname() */
```

There is some **casting** of pointers and `struct`s in regards to the hostname / IP address resolving, which can be confusing and easy place to make a mistake, so verify that is working as you expect it is.

```
 in_addr_t ip;
 ...

 GetIP(google, &ip);   /* I changed the parameters */
 printf("IP address = %x (%s)\n", 
     ip, 
     inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr*)&ip)));
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll check that as soon as posible (that will be tomorrow). I would bet GetIp is ok, but here it is: http://pastebin.com/JZVr2Ndn

Comment: Okay, `GetIP` looks okay, and the `inet_addr` _reverses_ the `inet_ntoa` back to the IP address in binary, so while being an indirect method, it should work. So do you understand the **two** biggest changes I made to your code? Namely, fixing the HTTP request string, and the `write` function. Make sure you _understand why_ the `write` function wasn't working. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

First, you're not checking how many bytes the [`write(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/write.2.html) call actually wrote to the socket. The return value of the call tells you that. Same for the [`read(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/write.2.html). TCP socket is a bi-directional stream, so as a rule always do both in a loop until expected number of bytes is transferred, `EOF` is read (zero return from `read(2)`), or an error occurred (which you are not checking for when reading either).

Then HTTP is rather complex protocol. Make yourself familiar with [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), especially application level connection management and transfer encodings.

#### Edit 0:

Hmm, there's no such thing as "simple" proxy. You need to manage multiple connections (at least client-to-proxy and proxy-to-server), so it's probably best to look into [`select(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html)/[`poll(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html)/[`epoll(4)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/epoll.4.html)/[`kqueue(2)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kqueue&sektion=2) family of system call, which allow you to [*multiplex*](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#select) I/O. This is usually combined with *non-blocking* sockets. Look into helper libraries like [`libevent`](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/). Look at how this is done in good web-servers/proxies like [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main). Sound like it's a lot for you to discover, but don't worry, it's fun :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It will take me a while to analyze your input, but see that what I want to create is an extremely simple proxy.

Comment: Why do you need those functions? If time isn't an issue, can't you just have two sockets; one for the server and one for the client, and read/write serially?

Comment: With blocking sockets waiting on input from one would block the other. With non-blocking sockets - maybe, but how would you know when to read? Would you spin and peg a core to 100%? Or would you sleep periodically? I/O multiplexing allows you to wait on both sockets with one call.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I've been implementing a small web proxy using my library called rzsocket [link to it](http://code.google.com/p/rzsocket).

One of the most difficult things I've found when implementing the web proxy, perhaps this might also be your problem, was that, in order to make the proxy work properly, I had to set keep-alive settings false. One way of doing this in FireFox, is accessing *about:config* address, and setting the value of `network.http.proxy.keep-alive` to `false`.